# XMPP Framework after register not call xmppStreamDidAuthenticate method(delegate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

i am stuck in one issue.when i register brand new User on my ejjaber server host it completely register on it after the it didn't get invoke in xmpp the delegate of like:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender;

 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error;
```

i am using the DidConnect of xmpp below:

```
 - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

      NSString *strPassward= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"userPassword"];

    NSError *error = nil;
     NSError *err;
 if(![[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:strPassward error:&err])
     {
        XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"available"];
     [sender sendElement:presence];
 }
 else
     {
     [self goOnline];
     NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
      XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"available"];
        [sender sendElement:presence];
 }
 [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:strPassward error:&error];
 }


- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[xmppStream sendElement:presence];

NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kXMPPmyJID"];
NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kXMPPmyPassword"];
[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
password = myPassword;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection is in making");
}

[self goOnline];
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

NSLog(@"Did not authenticate");
NSLog(@"didNotAuthenticate Method");

if(isRegister == TRUE)
{
    [xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:nil];
    NSError * err = nil;

    if(![xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error registering: %@", err);

        [self performSelector:@selector(connect1) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

    }

 }
}
- (void)goOnline
{
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
XMPPSystemInputActivityMonitor *activiyMonitor = [[XMPPSystemInputActivityMonitor alloc]init];
activiyMonitor.inactivityTimeInterval = 1;
[activiyMonitor addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
NSLog(@"Active : %d",[activiyMonitor isActive]);


UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Successfull!!!"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected"]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
 }
-(void)connect1
 {
      //isOpen = YES;
      NSError *error = nil;
      [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error];

   }
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue will be very helpful. Let me know if you need any additional info.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You talk about delegate, but where is it set?

Comment: where is your delegate method????

Comment: it's on xmppframework ,above all method's are on my appdel class.

Comment: Hi dhaval, I am facing same problem, have you found any solution of it?

Comment: @Student hey you may given username and password wrong ,check twice this in registerwithpassword method .